# Android, How to optionally include stuff based on API level

Tags: android, api

I have an app that opens various sub activies. Whenever the mobile is on API level 11+, I would like to show a button to open an activity that opens a calendar.

However, when e.g. designing the activity XML, I get error:

> View requires API level 11 (current min is 8):
>       activity_calendar.xml

Is there any way to markup xml/code files that they should only be avilable/compile-for API level 11... And then write code that based API-level includes the option to show/open the calanedar activity requiring aPI level 11?

This is a general question although in my case, it is caused by wanting to use CalendarView.
(I know there are some Apache version 2.0 license calendar alternatives which I am currently considering.)

Comment: You always have the option of creating xml resources(drawables, layouts etc) based on API levels. In code however you'd have to test on which version you are and use/not use the new APIs.

Comment: (I have already placed the XML file in "example/res/layout-v11", but I stil get the same error.)

Answer (score 3):

For code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) { 
    // do stuff for newer than Gingerbread
}
```

For XML

```
/res/layout-v8
```

Change the versions as you need.

Comment: (I have already placed the XML file in "example/res/layout-v11", but I stil get the same error.)